# Siddhi http-sink ignore ssl certificate error

Tags: ssl, wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

Reading from [Siddhi-io-http](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/1.0.41/#http-sink) I can't make sense of how to bypass ssl certification errors (i.e: expired or self signed).

There's a parameter called **ssl.verify.client** but no information about which values it accepts.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Full exception

```
[2018-11-16 10:54:29,871]  WARN {io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline} - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception. io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:281)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1215)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1127)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1364)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1272)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:145)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501)
```

Comment: For others who are looking for an answer, I've opened up a documentation issue on wso2/siddhi-io-http repo. You can find it in this [link](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-io-http/issues/94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved with:
 https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-http/issues/94

Now it's possible to bypass ssl certificate verification.